# AWS API Gateway expects the request URL to be encoded twice

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

My API is a request that can potentially have spaces in the pathParameters.

`/data/{id}/hello/{Some message with a space}`.
A sample request would be `/data/23/hello/Say%20Hi`

My angular code from the frontend encodes the request URL that is sent out to the AWS API Gateway but I get the following error.

```
`The Canonical String for this request should have been
'GET
/data/23/hello/Sayr%2520Hi`
```

My API gateway has a velocity template the decodes the parameters using `$util.urlDecode()`

Comment: Don't encode it and pass it through - what does it say then?

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same problem.
I've been stuck for a day.

If you are using **HttpApi** it cannot be solved.

Nevertheless, if you use **RestApi** I managed to make this work.

Specifically, you should use the URL Path Parameters.

You should:

1. Add a resource containing the */{variable}*
2. Add a Url Path Parameter in the Integration Request Configuration with *name* `variable` and *mapped from* `method.request.path.variable`

Notice that the solution may depend on the integration type that you are using.

In the screenshot below you can see how I'm redirecting all the received traffic to a NetworkLoadBalancer.
The resource has the variable */{proxy+}*, the endpoint URL has the *{proxy}*, and, in the URL Path Parameters, I've configured the mapping `method.request.path.proxy`.

[image]